# Ews, Body message in wrong encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exchangewebservices

In my MVC project, iam using ews to create and update appointments in outlook calendar I have a small problem. When I create / update an appointment in the outlook calendar with ews, the body message not showing correct !

I am adding

```
appt.Body = "rådgivning Møde"
```

And in outlook calendar, this message will be displayed as:  r?dgivning M?de

```
Appointment appt = Appointment.Bind(ExchangeServerConnection, apptID, new 
PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Body, AppointmentSchema.TextBody, AppointmentSchema.LegacyFreeBusyStatus));    

if (appt.LegacyFreeBusyStatus == appstatus)
{
    appt.Subject = subject;
    appt.Body = message;
    appt.LegacyFreeBusyStatus = LegacyFreeBusyStatus.Busy;

    //set explicit mode to SendToNone. Default mode is SendToAllAndSavecopy, it converts appointment to meeting.
    SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode mode = SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToNone;

    appt.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, mode);
```

Comment: I would suggest you enable tracing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633676(v=exchg.80).aspx in your code and then post the XML that is being sent to the server. It should all be UTF8 so it shouldn't be a problem but this will tell you either way what is being posted to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the content encoding (see this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47032977/php-sending-email-with-cyrillic-ukrainian-text/47093524#47093524) as well). So your body must be flagged as UTF-8 or something which fits your needs via the following if you use HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Fore more info's see the [Microsoft howto here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh545614%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx).